# Why are registers name in assembly cryptic

Tags: cpu, assembly

Why are registers named so short - EAX, EBX,...etc They could have easily made the names more
descriptive rather than encrypted like that.

Comment: They are very descriptive, once you know [the history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125854/14176811).

Comment: Better than register_the_first, register_the_second, register_the_third etc.

Comment: They *are* descriptive. For example, SP stands for *stack pointer*.